# Xcode Debug Console Output Changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This might seem like a silly question, but it's bugging me.

I recently had to switch provisioning profiles from my personal to my company. This was due to the fact that we needed to install our app for testing on 40 or so iPads. Regardless, in the process of this happening, the debug console seems to have changed.

It no longer outputs the normal debug console stuff - only NSLog statements, etc. For instance, before it would show [switching to process 0xblahblah], among other things such as general information about the product, etc. Now it does not. What might be causing this, or what settings can I look at to get these messages back? I'm afraid this is going to mess with error reporting in the console in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem like an LLDB and GDB issue it seems that xcode has changed the debugger form one to another

It seems that you changed the active schema, this may switch from one debugger to another the default debugger is LLDB, i personally prefer GDB

For changing debugger pelase read this
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html

Comment: Now that I think about it, I did update something with the compiler. This fixed it, thank you! I was running GDB previously, and LLDB after I switched.

Comment: It happened to me too, after preparing the app for archiving the schema changed and hence LLDB was set, i had to change it manually to GDB,

Also please dont forget to accept :)

Comment: Yep, there is a time limit on how fast I can do it. One more minute :P